# absoluteでは回り込みができない？

Tags: css, html5

bootstrapを使ってサイトを作っているのですがposition:absoluteで配置した要素の隣にdiv要素を配置してブラウザ幅を縮小するとdiv要素の中身がabsolute指定した要素にめり込んでしまいます。ネットでみるとabsoluteした要素にfloatが使えないようなのですがどうにか使える方法をご存じの方はいないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

[`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/position#Value) は

> **absolute**
>   要素のためのスペースが確保されません。

とあるように、他の要素は当該要素が存在しなかったものとしてレイアウトが行われます。当然回り込むことはありません。

記載されている質問文だけではどのようなレイアウトを検討されているか第三者にはわかりませんので、上記動作を念頭にスタイルを検討してください。

Answer (score 0):

`absolute`した要素に`float`は使えません。隣のdiv要素に`absolute`、`float`、`margin`、`padding`等の設定で調整は可能かと思います。